# Rails dump and load only specific tables between environments

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I found a lot of [documentation](https://coderwall.com/p/90qymq/how-to-transfer-data-seamlessly-between-various-ruby-on-rails-environments-and-databases) on how to dump the whole database and load it in a different environment but I don't want the *whole* database.

I need to dump and load only specific tables between environments.

For instance I need the `results` table from production in my testing environment but I don't want the `users` table.

Answer (score 0):

Use `yaml_db` gem

`rake db:data:dump_dir`
   ->   Dump contents of database to curr_dir_name/tablename.extension (defaults to yaml)

remove the unnecessary table files from the dir and then

`rake db:data:load_dir`   ->   Load contents of db/data_dir into database